# ASP.NET button and Jquery works together?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an `ASP button`, when I click this button, first I want to run code behind progress such as data delete, update..

After this progress, I want to run`Jquery` function  related this button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your server-side event handler can call ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to invoke jQuery in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to post back to the server so you can run your code, and when you return, you want to run some jquery.  Is that correct?

If so, you'll need to inject some jquery into the response after you do your work.

So your code-behind will delete a record or run an update, then write some jquery to the response which will run when the page is built on the client.  You might want to use the `Page.RegisterStartupScript` method to do this.

An alternative is to go down the ajax route, but that's a bit more complicated.

Comment: actually , i have an update panel , and when i click the button async postback is happened.

Comment: Then yes, what gWiz said I think - use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.  to be honest though, I haven't used update panels before so I don't know.  You should probably put things like this in the question :).